# Could not connect to development server on

Tags: android, react-native

I had some trouble with Android emulator in Android Studio and react native bundler.

All environment that I run the project before then was same but the connection error was occurred.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll try. :)

Comment: Maybe you could [edit] details of error into your question to be make it more useful for future readers.

Comment: Thank you for moving your solution into an Answer. It fits Stack Overflow's format much better that way. As mentioned, some additional details in the question would be helpful, so future readers can find the question and see that it's similar to the problem they are having, and so the question isn't too broad/unclear (e.g. fits too many problems/not sure which problem it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To try to solve this error, I had successfully made a new Android emulator.

That made me think that the Android emulator had some problem, but then I remembered that the Android emulator had been updated and that update included a new boot option, **'Quick boot'**. Previously, it only had the **'Cold boot'** option.

Changing the boot option to 'Cold boot' has solved my connection problem.

Comment: I've edited your answer to be clearer in English, please let me know if I have the facts correct.